# IDAPython load PDB-file of analysed binary

Tags: idapython, debugging-symbols, automation

in a python-script which I'm writing I need the possibility to load via IDA-Python the PDB-File of the analysed binary (PE-File).

I know how to load a PDB-File via GUi but I need this scripted.

Has anybody an idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

greetz Daniel :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the SDK, the PDB loader is implemented as an IDA plugin (see the SDK, e.g: `\idasdk67\plugins\pdb`).

The plugin name is "pdb", so you can call the plugin directly, like this:

```
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("pdb", call_code)
```

Where `call_code` is an `enum` defined in `\idasdk67\plugins\pdb\common.h`,

0, 1 and 2 are already defined and will ask for user input, but if you want to silently load a pdb for the actually loaded PE file, you can pass a value greater than 2, e.g.:

```
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("pdb", 3)
```

That should do the trick (at least it worked for me :)

```
Python>idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("pdb", 3)
PDB: using DIA dll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VC\msdia90.dll"
PDB: DIA interface version 9.0
ntkrpamp.pdb: not found, trying with the input file Z:\Reverse\Windows\win8.1\x86\6.3.9600\ntoskrnl.exe
Trying loadDataForExe with ffffffff
loadDataForExe: 0
PDB: loaded 2055 types
PDB: total 22027 symbols loaded for Z:\Reverse\Windows\win8.1\x86\6.3.9600\ntoskrnl.exe
True
```

Comment: at first thx al lot for your fast reply :-) It seems like that this plugin points in the right direction, but unfortunately I have to find a way to tell IDA to search/load the PDB-File for a certain path. I looked in \idasdk67\plugins\pdb\ but coulnd't find anything useful :-/ Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: @Daniel Why not going the other way around: append the desired path for your PDBs to your _NT_SYMBOL_PATH so IDA can find it?